# Get all functions that exist in JavaScript object (including nested functions)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get all of the functions in a JavaScript object?

Consider the following object:

```
var myObject = 
{ 
    method: function () 
    { 
        this.nestedMethod = function () 
        { 
        } 
    },
    anotherMethod: function() { } 
});
```

If I pass it into the function below I will get this result:

```
method
anotherMethod
```

(function to get all function names)

```
function properties(obj) 
{
    var output = "";
    for (var prop in obj) {
        output += prop + "<br />";
        try
        {
            properties(obj[prop]);
        }
        catch(e){}
    }
    return output;
}
```

How can I make this output:

```
method
nestedMethod
anothermethod
```

Comment: You can't do that without calling `method`.

Comment: @Paulpro: It would be beyond difficult.  It would be the halting problem.

Comment: Not to mention `$.getJSON("...", function(result) { self[result.name] = function() { ... })`

Comment: And yes, there are libraries that do that.  (eg, Google API client)

Comment: @SLaks You're right, it would be uncomputable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the elements of objects.
The function in the object is not an object.
So just create an object from the function, and iterate over it to check it.

This works:

```
function properties(obj) {
    var output = "";
    for (var prop in obj) {
        output += prop + "<br />";

        // Create object from function        
        var temp = new obj[prop]();

        output += properties(temp);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/b6r62/

It's a bit dirty though, it doesn't take arguments in consideration.

Answer (score 3):

`nestedMethod` is only created after running the function.

You can call every function on the object to see if they create more functions, but that's a horrible idea.